# useParams returns ':1', ':2', ':3' instead of '1' , '2', '3'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I'm trying to use useParams reactrouterhook to get id of superhero, to further make request to my server with such id. When in RQsuperherous.js I click on Link and get transported on adress http://localhost:3000/SuperHeroes/:2 as intended, yet in console.log my id equils = ':1', ':2', ':3', and so on, and I cant make request to server.

I'm using react router 6.x
I'm not sure about adress '/SuperHeroes/:id' in App.js. Maybe it should be nested.

my App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BasicLayout } from './pages/BasicLayout';
import { SuperHerous } from './pages/SuperHerous.page';
import { RQSuperHeroes } from './pages/RQSuperHeroes.page';
import { Home } from './pages/Home.page';
import { SuperHero } from './pages/SuperHero.page';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<BasicLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/SuperHerous" element={< SuperHerous />} />
        <Route path="/SuperHeroes/:id" element={< SuperHero />} />
        <Route path="/RQSuperHeros" element={< RQSuperHeroes />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my superHero page

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSuperHero } from '../hooks/useSuperHero';

export const SuperHero = () => {
  const id  = useParams();
  const { isLoading, data, isError, error } = useSuperHero({id});

  console.log(id)

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <h2>{error.message}</h2>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <h1>{data.alterago}</h1>
      xfcghjk
    </div>
  )
}
```

my RQsuperherous.js

```
import { useSuperHero } from "../hooks/useSuperHero"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const RQSuperHeroes = () => {
  const onSuccess = (data) => {
    console.log('Perform side effect after data fetching', data)
  }

  const onError = (error) => {
    console.log('Perform side effect after encountering error', error.message)
  }

  const { data, isLoading, isError, error, isFetching, refetch } = useSuperHero({onSuccess, onError});

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <h2>{error.message}</h2>
  }

  console.log(isLoading, isFetching)

  return (
    <>
      <div>RQ SuperHeroes Page</div>
      <button onClick={refetch}>Fetch heroes</button>
      {
        data && data.length && (
          data.map(el => {
            return (
            <Link to={`SuperHeroes/:${el.id}`} key={el.id}>
              <div className='super' >
                <h2>{el.name}</h2>
                <p>{el.alterego}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
            )
          })
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Edited:
if in RQsuperherous component in Link path change to `SuperHeroes/${el.id}`
I have an error in console : No routes matched location

> "/RQSuperHeros/SuperHeroes/1"

Comment: You're adding the colon explicitly: `to={\`SuperHeroes/:${el.id}\`}`

Comment: and how it should be?

Comment: You should remove the colon. change it to ```to={`SuperHeroes/${el.id}`}```.

Comment: Well if you don't want the colon, did you try _taking it out_? `path="/SuperHeroes/:id"` doesn't mean you have to literally include a colon every time, it's indicating a parameter as a placeholder.

Comment: look at edited section

Comment: That's a _different_ problem - look at your routes, you don't define `/RQSuperHeros/SuperHeroes/:id`, you define `/SuperHeroes/:id` and a _separate_ `/RQSuperHeros` route.

Comment: Just add a `/` to the `to` prop: ```to={`/SuperHeroes/:${el.id}`}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

http://localhost:3000/SuperHeroes/:2

The `:` in the route definition is not meant to be in the real route

Use this address and check the `id` variable

http://localhost:3000/SuperHeroes/2